# SwiftUI Localization of Strings inside an Array

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization

I'm trying to localize my App in English and German and everything worked for now, expect the strings inside an array apparently get not localized.

I have this array, which holds the options for my Picker:

```
let sorting = ["Newest First", "Oldest First"]
```

This is my Picker, which works correctly function wise:

```
Picker("Sort by", selection: $sortingSelection) {
    ForEach(sorting, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            .font(.footnote)
    }
}
.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

And this is the correleting Localizable.strings (German):

```
"Newest First" = "Neueres Zuerst";
"Oldest First" = "Älteres Zuerst";
```

So I tried just writing it as strings, which is the easiest way to use localization now.

I also tried using the it as a variable, but this doesn't work:

```
let localizedString1 = "Newest First"
let localizedString2 = "Oldest First"

let sorting = [localizedString1, localizedString2]
```

I also saw this post:

[Swift: Localize an Array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905706/swift-localize-an-array-of-strings)

but like the comment on the answer says, is there a way to get some example code? Or is there a better method now?

Comment: I'm not using SwiftUI, but could this be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349719/can-i-pass-a-string-containing-markdown-to-custom-view ?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be localized?   How are you localizing a string that's not in an array?

Comment: @Shadowrun in SwiftUI you don't need to write anything else anymore than the string itself, it checks if there is a localization or not, so I thought it's gonna be automatic inside an array too

Comment: This does not work for String variables. You need to localize the variable when putting it in the text

Comment: Is that because a raw string would be type inferred as LocalizedStringKey to use the init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, comment: StaticString? = nil) initialiser, and your array is [String] not [LocalizedStringKey]

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62042521/13944750)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Text documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text) :

> If you intialize a text view with a variable value, the view uses the init(*:) initializer, which doesn’t localize the string. However, you can request localization by creating a LocalizedStringKey instance first, which triggers the init(*:tableName:bundle:comment:) initializer instead:

```
// Don't localize a string variable...
Text(writingImplement)


// ...unless you explicitly convert it to a localized string key.
Text(LocalizedStringKey(writingImplement))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Picker("Select Category", selection: $transactionTypeString) {
    ForEach(transactionTypes, id:\.self) {
        Text(LocalizedStringKey($0))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array defaults to type `String`, you can specify the type to `LocalizedStringKey`

```
let sorting: [LocalizedStringKey] = ["Newest First", "Oldest First"]
```

You might have to change the selection type too to make them match.